# How to use "hinder" in a sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

Is this correct?

> "Will admission truly hinder your chances of success?"

Is it hinder chances "for", "from", or "of"?

Comment: _Hinder_ here does not affect which preposition to use, that is determined by _chances_ in your example.  Perhaps I misunderstand your question.

Comment: I would say *diminish* is a better word than *hinder* here, actually, since it's referring to the effect on your chances. *Hinder* is usually used to describe an effect on something more active — *this will* ***hinder*** *movement,* e.g. You might even just say "Will admission truly hinder your success?" *Chances,* on the other hand, are usually *diminished* or possibly *decreased.*

Answer (score 1):

Saying "... hinder your [chances of success]" I understand "of success" to be a modifier of "chances".  That is a reasonable sentence, and "chance of success" is a fairly common idiom. But "diminish" may be a better verb to use. You mean the chance of success is made smaller, and diminish is the right word here.

Saying "... hinder your chances [from success]" is very odd, but I parse it as an adverbial phrase, modifying the verb. If I say "John hindered Jane from running" it means that John made running difficult for Jane; so "... admission hinder your chances from success" would mean "admission makes it difficult for your chances to be successful". That's nonsense! A person can be successful, but a chance can't be successful.

So "from" is grammatically correct, but when you work out what it means, it doesn't make sense!